# Iterating through edges with custom defined edge properties of boost::adjacency_list

Tags: c++, boost, boost-graph, boost-property-map

I'm working on a simulation program which uses boost::adjacency_list to represent a graph. The edges have costume designed properties

```
struct edge_data{
    const float linear_cost, const_cost;
    std::queue<*Agent> agents;

    edge_data(float lin, float con) : linear_cost(lin),const_cost(con) {}
};
```

After trying several ways, I haven't found a way to create a property_map which returns the full EdgeData for each edge, or any other way to iterate through and modify edges. Is it possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You ask the edge bundle from the graph, either

- using the `boost::edge_bundle_t` property map:

  ```
  auto pmap = boost::get(boost::edge_bundle, my_graph);
  edge_data& data = pmap[my_edge_descriptor];
  ```
- using the convenience accessors:

  ```
  edge_data& data = mygraph[my_edge_descriptor];
  ```
- or using specific property maps for a sub-property:

  ```
  auto costmap = boost::get(&edge_data::linear_cost, my_graph);
  float cost = costmap[my_edge_descriptor];
  ```